# Logstash json filter. Parsing json string in json message

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I have next json, and json as string in input, I want to parse [value][value] field in value level valid json (not string)

```
{
  "partitionId": 3,
  "value": {
    "value": "{\"system\":\"system\",\"route\":\"route\",\"type\":\"Z9\"}",
  },
  "valueType": "VARIABLE"
}
```

And next filter, but this not work for me

```
filter { 
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
    if [valueType] == "VARIABLE" {
        json {
            source => "[value][value]"
            target => "values"
        }
    }
    mutate {
        remove_field => [ "timestamp", "kafka" ]
    }
}
```

How I can parse this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just missed it :)

```
input { 
  stdin { } 
}  

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    target => "message"
  }
if [valueType] == "VARIABLE" {
  json {
    source => "[message][value][value]" ##You missed it here
    target => "[value]"
  }

}
 output { stdout { codec => rubydebug  }}
```